# How to disable the method return type hint in IntellijIdea scala plugin

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

Intellij Idea scala plugin automatically show the method's return type in gray which is annoying in most cases.

How to suppress this feature

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This feature has been added in [IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/specials/idea/whatsnew.html)

> The editor can now show inline hints for parameter names, method
>   result types, and variable types. You can also easily use the settings
>   to customize when such a hint should be shown.

You can disable it from `Preference` -> `Editor` -> `General` -> `Appearance`

[image: How to switch scala function return type hints]

Uncheck "Show function return type hints(Scala)"

Or simply right click on the type hints

[image]

And click on `Function return type hints`

Once you disable it, the former way is the only way to re-enable it.

Answer (score 2):

You can create shortcuts for toggling this in Preferences > Keymap 
and from there follow Main Menu > Plugins > Scala > Function return type hints 
Or search for "hints" in the keymap settings tab. Having a good keymap to toggle this is actually really helpful - and probably most of all when reading someone else's code.[image: Where to set the "Function return type hint" in Intellij 2019.2]

It would be interesting to have feedback about what people here think good shortcuts for this should be.